# Fermionic inner product in curved spacetime

Tags: quantum-field-theory, qft-in-curved-spacetime

In Birrell & Davies "Quantum Fields in Curved Space", chapter 3, they mention the inner product for scalar fields over some cauchy surface $\Sigma$:

$$(\phi_1,\phi_2)= - i \int_{\Sigma} \phi_1(x) \overleftrightarrow{\partial_{\mu}} \phi^{*}_2(x)[-g_{\Sigma}(x)]^{1/2} d\Sigma^{\mu} \hspace{2cm} (3.28)$$

At the end of the chapter they generalize the quantization to higher spin fields, without talking about the inner product. I wonder how the inner product looks like for fermionic fields in curved space?

Comment: This is addressed on page 69 in Saharian's *Quantum Field Theory in Curved Spacetime*, [`http://training.hepi.tsu.ge/rtn/activities/sources/LectQFTrev.pdf`](http://training.hepi.tsu.ge/rtn/activities/sources/LectQFTrev.pdf).

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly great notes